# How do I manually install or force the install of a plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I manually install a plugin in Eclipse? Or how do I force the installer to install a plugin, even when it doesn't want to?

E.g., I am trying to downgrade a plugin (an update for which contained a bug that I cannot work with). I have tried going to `About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installation History` and selecting a previous configuration, but I get errors trying to revert to one. I have also downloaded the all-in-one update for the previous version of the plugin I want to roll-back. But if I go to `Install New Software -> Add -> Archive` then I can select the update, but when I try to install it I am told that the plugin I'm trying to install "will be ignored because a newer version is already installed".

I need a way to install the plugin manually or force the installer to install the older version of the plugin. Doe anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should uninstall the current version of the plug-in before installing the older one.
go to About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software and uninstall the plug-in you want to downgrade. 
then try again installing it going toInstall New Software -> Add -> Archive...

saluti

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately, when I find the plugin I want to uninstal, the `Uninstall` button is grayed-out. I can only uninstall the top-level plugin (epp.package.php) and not sub-plugins. Maybe this is because I installed the "Eclipse for PHP Developers" download of Eclipse?

Comment: yes: it seems that you can't uninstall plugins of the "basic installation". you could try to manually delete the plugin jar from the plugin directory and copy the older version jar in the same directory, but I don't guarantee the result

Comment: Ok, I deleted the org.ecipse.php.* plugins and features from the Eclipse installation. I did try adding the plugins/features from the update, but I couldn't get Eclipse to load them. In the end, having manually removed the PHP features/plugins, I powered-up Eclipse and installed the update via the `Install New Software` option.

Answer (score 0):

There is some difference between each Eclipse version to locate the feature. Which version did you use ? 3.3 ?

I can't say where you will find the option but start by removing the installedv ersion and retry to install the older.

If you realy want to install it you can also try to find the archive and extract the content into your Eclipse folder (It may have two folder features and plugin).

/!\Take care about plugin dependency and compatibilty/!\ Make a backup of your installation before.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.6.1 (Helios)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the top level plugin.

Try to reinstall it without selecting the last version of the plugin. May be you can select and older version in this step or install the expected sub-plugin version later.

Or

Find which version of "epp.package.php" use the plugin version you need. Install it. And if needed try to update some plugin/sub-plugin and check if your sub-plugin is not in the update list.